# Get every key starting with a prefix in Node.JS from JSON Data

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

Hey so I have a JSON string:

```
{
    "cmd.test1":"test1",
    "cmd.test2":"test2",
    "ab.test1":"nthing"
}
```

and I want to get all keys (in this case it's cmd.test1 or cmd.test2) starting with a prefix of "cmd.". I am unable to get what I should do. Can someone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Possible solution using `Object.keys` and `Array#filter`.

- `RegExp` solution

```js
var obj = {
    "cmd.test1":"test1",
    "cmd.test2":"test2",
    "ab.test1":"nthing"
}, 
res = Object.keys(obj).filter(v => /^cmd/.test(v));

console.log(res);
```

- `String#startsWith` solution

```js
var obj = {
    "cmd.test1":"test1",
    "cmd.test2":"test2",
    "ab.test1":"nthing"
}, 
res = Object.keys(obj).filter(v => v.startsWith('cmd'));

console.log(res);
```